# cannot find module file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am doing my Udemy course and I am stack now ;( If anyone can help me it would be great!
So the Error said "Error: Cannot find module '/Users/yui/Desktop/todolist-v1/date.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/yui/Desktop/todolist-v1/app.js"

but I am not sure why they cannot find module.
Thanks in advance.

app.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

let items = ["Buy Food","Cook Food","Eat Food"];
let workItems = [];

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){

 let day = date();

 res.render("list", {ListTitle: day, NewListItems: items});

});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

 let item = req.body.newItem;

 if(req.body.list === "Work"){
   workItems.push(item);
   res.redirect("/work");
 }else{
   items.push(item);
   res.redirect("/")
 }
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
   res.render("about")
});

app.get("/work", function(req, res){
   res.render("list", {ListTitle: "Work List", NewListItems: workItems});
});

app.post("/work", function(req, res){
   let item = req.body.newItem;
   workItems.push(item);
   res.redirect("/work");
})


app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

date.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6

module.exports = getDate;

function getDate(){

 let today = new Date();

 let currentDay = today.getDay();

 let day = "";
 　
 let options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long"
 };

 let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

};
```

Comment: Can You try this? `const { getDate } = require(__dirname + "/date.js");`

Comment: you shouldn't need to require with `__dirname` it should just be a relative path like `cosnt date = require("./date.js")`

Comment: How is the file structure of the project composed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If app.js and date.js in the same folder you didn't need to use __dirname.

Just use this line of code for import any js file.

```
const getDate = require('./date.js');
```

For example if this your project structure

```
/main_app_folder/app.js
/main_app_folder/helpers/data.js
```

You can use this line of code for import any js file inside helpers folder from app.js

```
const getDate = require('./helpers/date.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of using `_dirname` in `const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");` Here is the explanation, why? 
In Node.js, `__dirname` is always the directory in which the currently executing script resides. So if you typed `__dirname` into `/dir1/dir2/myscript.js`, the value would be `/d1/d2`.

By contrast, `.` gives you the directory from which you ran the `node` command in your terminal window (i.e. your working directory) when you use libraries like `path` and `fs`. Technically, it starts out as your working directory but can be changed using `process.chdir()`.

The exception is when you use `.` with `require()`. The path inside `require` is always relative to the file containing the call to `require`.

## For example...

Let's say your directory structure is

```
|--dir1
  |--dir2
     pathtest.js
```

and `pathtest.js` contains

```
var path = require("path");
console.log(". = %s", path.resolve("."));
console.log("__dirname = %s", path.resolve(__dirname));
```

and you do

```
cd /dir1/dir2
node pathtest.js
```

you get

```
. = /dir1/dir2
__dirname = /dir1/dir2
```

Your working directory is `/dir1/dir2` so that's what `.` resolves to. Since `pathtest.js` is located in `/dir1/dir2` that's what `__dirname` resolves to as well.

However, if you run the script from `/dir1`

```
cd /dir1
node dir2/pathtest.js
```

you get

```
. = /dir1
__dirname = /dir1/dir2
```

In that case, your working directory was `/dir1` so that's what `.` resolved to, but `__dirname` still resolves to `/dir1/dir2`.

#### Using `.` inside `require`...

If inside `dir2/pathtest.js` you have a `require` call into include a file inside `dir1` you would **always** do

```
require('../thefile')
```

because the path inside `require` is always relative to the file in which you are calling it. It has nothing to do with your working directory.